# Using external web space from domain (DNS)

Tags: dns

I got a client that uses provider A for webhosting purposes with domain A. I registered a second domain B on a different provider B for my client.

How can I link to the web folder on provider A with my domain B? I don't want to use a simple redirect - it should be the same as using the web space with domain A. (so the URL structure &c. will remain)

Edit: I already got the nameservers from provider A, but I don't know how to set and use them.

Comment: Are you saying you want both domains to point to the same content?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I try.

Answer (score 1):

**Domain Aliases**

On your primary provider (A) where your site is hosted, you will want to ask them to add a domain alias (or parked domain) for `domainB.com`.

Different hosting providers use different names to describe domain aliases, so the terminology may differ at your host.

If you give them the domain name and tell them it should point to the same document root, they should understand.

**DNS**

For DNS, you need to point domain B's DNS records to the same IP address as used for domain A.

On the nameservers for `domainB.com`, you will need to add A records to point `domainB.com` and `www.domainB.com` to the IP address used by `domainA.com`.

Where you setup the DNS records for `domainB.com` will depend on what nameservers the domain uses.

Answer (score 0):

It will most probably be a matter of finding out how to set the nameservers from whoever provided the domain name. They should have some information or support to help you, so you would be best to contact them.